# Calculating the internal resistance

Tags: batteries, electricity

I have build a circuit:

The power source is a battery. The rectangle (below the amperemeter) is a resistance.

I have measured U (in Volt) and I (in Ampere) for the whole discharge process. Now I would like to calculate the internal resistance of the battery during the discharge process.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you read anything about that topic?

Comment: Also could well be homework.

Comment: I've tried a few things, but I'm not sure if it's true. So I asked here to get the info directly from experts

Comment: You edited your question and now the statement "below the amperemeter [sic]" makes no sense. Why did you remove the schematic?

Answer (score 1):

The measurement results you obtained are not enough to determine the internal resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsQpnK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You measured the voltage across BATT and Rinternal, and the current through them, (green coloured variables below), but it still gives you 1 equation with 2 (red coloured) unknown variabless (which has no unique solution)

$$ \color{green}{V_{load}} =  \color{red}{V_{BATT}} -  \color{green}{I_{load}} \color{red}{R_{load}}$$

You need to measure the battery voltage

- without load (\$V_{open}\$). With (hardly) no current, there is no voltage drop across \$R_{internal}\$ and therefore \$V_{open}=V_{batt}\$
- with the resistance load (\$V_{load}\$) and the load current (\$I_{load}\$)

With those, you can determine the internal resistance.

$$ R_{internal} = \frac{ V_{open} - V_{load} }{I_{load} } $$

Comment: But I thought I know `V_open` - it's 1.5 V ?

Comment: There is no mention of that in your question.

Comment: That depends. Typically the voltage lowers when the battery discharges

Comment: Ok sorry. But because of that I have measured the voltage of the battery continuously

Comment: You alternated the measurements continueously? You can **not** measure Vopen and Vload **at the same time**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't described it well. I measured continuously (every 5 second) U and I (see circuit plan), but I thought `V_open` is 1.5V because the packaging says it.

Comment: No, as said, the voltage drops during discharging. So, you need to measure it at (almost) the same time.

Comment: Ok. What is the difference between `V_open` and `V_load` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102810/discussion-between-huisman-and-user11325078).

Comment: Or we can use this equation \$\Large R_{INT} = R_{LOAD} \left(\frac{V_{open}}{V_{load}} -1 \right)\$ Where V_open is battery voltage without any load resistance conneted to the battery.

Comment: ... and we are sure Rload is constant, so, doesn't change due to e.g. heating up (Still, nice addition)